# Programmatically delete item from Windows Recycle Bin without UI dialog

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, recycle-bin

I'm using `IContextMenu` with `"delete"` verb to erase items from recycle bin, but it brings up the UI dialog even if I use`CMIC_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI` flag. Is there another way to delete files from recycle bin without showing the dialog?

```cpp
IContextMenu* contextMenu;
recycleBin->GetUIObjectOf(0, 1, (LPCITEMIDLIST*)(&pidl), IID_IContextMenu, 0, (LPVOID *)&contextMenu);
CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO ci;
memset(&ci, 0, sizeof(ci));
ci.fMask = CMIC_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI;
ci.cbSize = sizeof(CMINVOKECOMMANDINFO);
ci.lpVerb = "delete";
contextMenu->InvokeCommand(&ci);
contextMenu->Release();
```

The full code including recycle bin object initialization and items enumeration is on [gist](https://gist.github.com/FreeSlave/6c7d8221498380cc8049b5a7443b682b)

Comment: [IFileOperation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shobjidl_core/nn-shobjidl_core-ifileoperation)

Comment: According to [Invoking commands on items in the Recycle Bin](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110901-00/?p=9753): "*One annoyance of the Recycle Bin is that, at least up until Windows 7, **it ignores the CMIC_MASK_FLAG_NO_UI flag. It always displays a confirmation dialog** if something dangerous is about to happen (like overwriting an existing file).*" So you would likely have to manually detect and dismiss the popup confirmation.

Comment: @JonathanPotter `IFileOperation`'s `DeleteItem` did the trick, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can install a [WH_CBT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) hook, and in its callback watch for an nCode of `HCBT_CREATEWND`. If you get a matching class name ('#32770 (Dialog)' ?) and a matching title either return a nonzero value from the callback, you can send [BM_CLICK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/bm-click) to click `Yes` button and the dialog will be closed automatically.

Code Sample:

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Ole2.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <shlwapi.h>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib,"Shlwapi.lib")

HHOOK g_hhook;

int main()
{
    OleInitialize(0);

    HINSTANCE hinstDLL = LoadLibrary(TEXT("D:\\xxx\\Dll_WH_CBT\\Debug\\Dll_WH_CBT.dll"));
    HHOOK(*AttachHookProc)(DWORD);
    AttachHookProc = (HHOOK(*)(DWORD)) GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "AttachHook");
    void(*RemoveHooks)(DWORD);
    RemoveHooks = (void(*)(DWORD))GetProcAddress(hinstDLL, "RemoveHooks");

    IShellFolder* desktop;
    if (FAILED(SHGetDesktopFolder(&desktop))) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to get desktop fodler" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    ...
    IEnumIDList* enumFiles;
    if (FAILED(recycleBin->EnumObjects(0, SHCONTF_FOLDERS | SHCONTF_NONFOLDERS | 
SHCONTF_INCLUDEHIDDEN, &enumFiles)))
    {
        std::cerr << "Could not enumerate recycle bin objects" << std::endl;
        recycleBin->Release();
        return -1;
    }

    AttachHookProc(0);

    ...
      
    RemoveHooks(0);
    enumFiles->Release();
    recycleBin->Release();

    OleUninitialize();
    return 0;
}
```

Dll:

```
// dllmain.cpp : Defines the entry point for the DLL application.
#include "pch.h"
#include <Windows.h>

HMODULE thisModule;
HHOOK g_hhook;

LRESULT CALLBACK CBTProc(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{        
    switch (nCode)
    {
    case HCBT_CREATEWND:
    {      
        HWND File_Window = FindWindow(L"#32770", L"Delete File"); 
        HWND Folder_Window = FindWindow(L"#32770", L"Delete Folder");
        if (File_Window)
        {
            HWND yes = FindWindowEx(File_Window, NULL, L"Button", L"&Yes");
            SendMessage(yes, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
            SendMessage(yes, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
        }
        if (Folder_Window)
        {
            HWND yes = FindWindowEx(Folder_Window, NULL, L"Button", L"&Yes");
            SendMessage(yes, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
            SendMessage(yes, BM_CLICK, 0, 0);
        }
        break;
    }
    default:
        break;
    }
    return CallNextHookEx(g_hhook, nCode, wParam, lParam);
}

#ifdef __cplusplus    //If used by C++ code.
extern "C" {        //we need to export the C interface
#endif
    _declspec(dllexport) HHOOK AttachHook(DWORD threadID) {
        g_hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, thisModule, threadID);

        return g_hhook;
    }
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

extern "C" {        //we need to export the C interface
    __declspec(dllexport) void RemoveHooks(DWORD)
    {
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(g_hhook);
    }
}

BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule,
                       DWORD  ul_reason_for_call,
                       LPVOID lpReserved
                     )
{
    thisModule = hModule;
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
    {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:      
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:

        break;
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```